# Put a file Json (array) into a zip file [Java]

Tags: java, json, zip

Hello I'm new to java and my english is not good as well lmao
I need to put a file json (it's an array json) in a file zip trought java but i tried multiple solution and doesn't work :(

this is my code:

```
     JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
     String desktopPath =(System.getProperty("user.home")+"\\"+"Desktop");
        new File(desktopPath+"\\Service Reply").mkdir();
    String definitivePath = (desktopPath +"\\"+"Service Reply"+"\\");
        
    
    Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(definitivePath+"daticliente.json"));

        File f = new File(definitivePath+"//"+"test1.zip");
        ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));
        ZipEntry e = new ZipEntry(definitivePath+"daticliente.json");
        out.putNextEntry(e);
        out.closeEntry();
        out.close();
```

any help ?
regards

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Please add error messages and expected vs. actual results etc.

Comment: hi ty for reply me, the code create the file zip but doesn't put the file json i've already created before in the file zip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a `ZipEntry` but you are not adding the file content, so your resulting file is empty. You have to read the file and add the contents to the `ZipOutputStream` instance. Here is an example:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class ZipFileExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        zipFile("README.md");
    }

    private static void zipFile(String filePath) {
        try {
            final var file = new File(filePath);
            final var zipFileName = file.getName().concat(".zip");

            final var fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(zipFileName);
            final var zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(fileOutputStream);

            zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file.getName()));

            final var bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath));
            zipOutputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
            zipOutputStream.close();

        } catch (final FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.err.format("The file %s does not exist", filePath);
        } catch (final IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("I/O error: " + ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: ty so much! is working have a nice day!